# jquery horizontal slide without toggle

Tags: jquery, animation, sliding

Let's assume we have a button and a div with text inside it. How can we slide the div horizontally (make it disappear) when pressing the button, and then slide it up again to it's original width, but **without using the animate({width:"toggle"}) command**?
http://codepen.io/AndrewRed/pen/MYmWzg

```
 <h5>PUSH</h5>
 <div class="container">Hello World</div>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h5").click(function(){
   $(".container").animate({width:"0"});
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use css transitions and classes:
from your code:
HTML:

```
<h5>PUSH</h5>
<div class="container">Hello World</div>
```

CSS:

```
h5{
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.container{
  background: orange;
  display: inline-block;
  width:90px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.3s, linear;
  -moz-transition: 0.3s, linear;
  -ms-transition: 0.3s, linear;
  -o-transition: 0.3s, linear;
  transition: 0.3s, linear;
}

.container.close{
  width:0;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("h5").click(function(){
    $(".container").toggleClass('close');
  });
```

link to code:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mymJYr